# How to stop the countdown in Google Sheet when the progress is complete?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I have made simple formula in cell I3:

```
=DAYS(TODAY(), I3)
```

It starts counting the days from day we receive the project. In column (K) we set a drop list, what it matters is complete. I want when we choose complete the counts stops.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scope you could use Apps Script to essentially copy the content of the cell and past it as value only when it becomes marked as complete.  I get this impression that this may not be in scope... but there is no formula that would stop the formula without you manually intervening with your current description.

However, if you are willing to add a column that includes the date that the project was completed, then you can use an if statement to basically switch between using Today() or the completed date.

If you had something like this...

[image]

you can use this formula to say if there is an "end date" use that, otherwise use Today().

```
=if(not(ISBLANK(J3)),Days(J3,I3),DAYS(TODAY(), I3))
```

If you still want to key off the "completed" drop down you can do the following...but you will still need to use a completed date to "stop" the calculation at that date.

```
=if(K3="Complete",Days(J3,I3),DAYS(TODAY(), I3))
```